# Use Babel in Visual Studio?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, babeljs

How to use Babel (https://babeljs.io/docs/setup/) in ASP.NET development environment?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Visual Studio CODE allows Babel development.
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vscode/archive/2015/07/06/vs-code-es6.aspx

Visual Studio 2015 has't fully implemented ES2015 yet, but it will be coming.

Comment: Yea, but Visual Studio CODE is NOT Visual Studio.